# GWT RequestFactory + ServiceLocator Bug

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I am using GWT 2.2 with RequestFactory. The app has an existing service layer (server side) so I am using a ServiceLocator to provide these implementations. My Proxy and RequestContexts specify the correct service and locator to use (as shown [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#using)). I am able to make basic requests for data but when I try to save, I get the following exception:

```
com.google.gwt.requestfactory.server.UnexpectedException: Could not instantiate Locator com.schedgy.core.service.OrganizationService. Is it default-instantiable?
at com.google.gwt.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.die(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:185)
at com.google.gwt.requestfactory.server.LocatorServiceLayer.newInstance(LocatorServiceLayer.java:222)
at com.google.gwt.requestfactory.server.LocatorServiceLayer.createLocator(LocatorServiceLayer.java:47)
at com.google.gwt.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.createLocator(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

OrganizationService is defined like:

```
// Parent class provides the generic Locator<Organization, String> methods
public class OrganizationService extends CompanyEntityService<Organization> {

        protected OrganizationDao organizationDao;

        protected UserDao userDao;

        protected RoleDao roleDao;

        @Inject
        public OrganizationService(
                OrganizationDao organizationDao,
                UserDao userDao,
                RoleDao roleDao) {

            super(organizationDao, Organization.class);

            this.organizationDao = organizationDao;
            this.userDao = userDao;
            this.roleDao = roleDao;
        }

... additional methods
}
```

My locator class looks like:

```
public class CompanyServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {

    protected Injector injector;

    public CompanyServiceLocator() {        
        injector = GuiceFactory.getInjector();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
        return injector.getInstance(clazz);
    }
}
```

The OrganizationProxy looks like:

```
@ProxyFor(value=Organization.class, locator=OrganizationService.class)
public interface OrganizationProxy extends CompanyEntityProxy {
... setters/getters defined here
}
```

The OrganizationRequest looks like:

```
@Service(value=OrganizationService.class, locator=CompanyServiceLocator.class)
public interface OrganizationRequest extends RequestContext {
...
}
```

The client side code looks something like:

```
OrganizationRequest req = organizationRequestFactory.request();
req.paginate(0, 10).fire(paginationReceiver); // Works!

req = organizationRequestFactory.request();
OrganizationProxy org = req.create(OrganizationProxy.class);
org.setName("test");
req.save(org).fire(receiver); // This causes the server side exception
```

It is obvious to me that ServiceLayerDecorator cannot instantiate OrganizationService because it does not have a default constructor, but this is why I am using Guice and have over-written the ServiceLocator to use Guice to create instances of the service. But why does the first call correctly use my ServiceLocator whereas the second does not?

Comment: What are the @Proxy and @Service annotations that you're using?  The error message looks like you have the non-default-instantiable OrganizationService being used as the target of a locator value in one of the annotations.

Comment: No, I am pretty sure they are correct. Again, it works fine when I am fetching data. I only have the problem when saving an entity. I updated the question to include the Proxy interface and request context so that you could see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locators must be default-instantiable.

```
@ProxyFor(value=Organization.class, locator=OrganizationService.class)
```

is where things are going off the rails.  If the `OrganizationService` is vending instances of `Organization` to fulfill the `Locator` interface, you'll need to make it default-instantiable or inject a `ServiceLayerDecorator` that implements `createLocator()`.

The reason that the first code sample works and not the second is that the second code sample is creating and mutating an `Organization` based on commands from the client.  In this case `Locator.create()` must be called by the RequestFactory server code.  Without knowing what `paginate()` returns to the client, I suspect that no instances of `Organization` are being returned since it would be necessary to call the `Locator.getId()` and `Locator.getVersion()` methods.

Comment: What is the purpose than of having CompanyServiceLocator provide an instance of OrganizationService? Are services (implementations of Locator) now being provided/instantiated by two different classes (ServiceLayerDecorator and implementations of ServiceLocator)?

Comment: Services are provided by ServiceLocators; entities are provided by Locators. RequestFactory creates either one (ServiceLocator or Locator) using their no-arg constructor, unless you provide a ServiceLayerDecorator to change that behavior. You might have a hard time understanding who does what because your service and your "Locator of Operation entities" are the same class in your case (and honestly, I don't quite understand why)

Comment: @Thomas, I have two distinct classes: CompanyServiceLocator provides a Service and OrganizationService provides a "Locator of Operation entities". I dont see how they are the same thing? Perhaps I have not done a good enough job setting up the question, but I believe the responsibilities are separated correctly. If not, I would like to hear why so that I could correct them.

Comment: What I meant is that OrganizationService is both your service and a Locator<Operation>. The fact is that your CompanyServiceLocator will provide an instance "as a service" (and if you have such a ServiceLocator, it probably means your service cannot simply be instantiated using its default constructor) and RequestFactory will use the default constructor to instantiate the class "as a Locator<Operation>". It's best IMO to have one class for the service and another one as the Locator for entities.

Comment: @Thomas, thanks for the clarification. I see what you are saying now.

Answer (score 1):

I am still confused on why two classes need to provide implementations for Locators, but here is how I was able to fix this problem.

Extend the default RequestFactoryServlet so that you can inject your custom ServiceLayerDecorator by default.

```
public class CompanyRequestFactoryServlet extends RequestFactoryServlet {

    public CompanyRequestFactoryServlet() {
        this(new DefaultExceptionHandler(), new CompanyServiceLayerDecorator());
    }

    public SchedgyRequestFactoryServlet(ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler,
            ServiceLayerDecorator... serviceDecorators) {
        super(exceptionHandler, serviceDecorators);
    }
}
```

Create a ServiceLayerDecorator to provide instances of your Locator's. I use Guice, so this was quite easy. GuiceFactory in the below code is just a singleton that provides an instance of the Guice Injector.

```
public class CompanyServiceLayerDecorator extends ServiceLayerDecorator {

    @Override
    public <T extends Locator<?, ?>> T createLocator(Class<T> clazz) {
        return GuiceFactory.getInjector().getInstance(clazz);
    }
}
```

Finally, update your web.xml to use your custom servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.core.requestfactory.CompanyRequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>requestFactoryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```